# Kubernetes ClusterIP Service ENV set incorrectly

Tags: kubernetes

I created a ClusterIP service that has 3 pods in the deployment:

`tornado-service   ClusterIP   10.107.117.119   <none>        8085/TCP       2m`

When I ssh into one of the pods it has these env variables:

```
TORNADO_SERVICE_PORT_8085_TCP_PROTO=tcp
TORNADO_SERVICE_PORT_8085_TCP=tcp://10.99.116.50:8085
TORNADO_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=10.99.116.50
```

Which doesn't match what `kubectl` gave me. When I curl another pod using the ENV ip address it hangs:

`curl -XPOST 10.99.116.50:8085`

But when I use the `kubectl` IP I get a 200 http response:

`curl -XPOST 10.107.117.119:8085`

Why is Kubernetes setting the service IP env incorrectly in my pods?

Comment: It is very, very suspicious that those two subnets are not in the same universe as each other, which smells like you have two different clusters, or you have the [`service-cluster-ip-range`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kube-controller-manager/) set to `10.0.0.0/8` or something. Also, separately, be aware those env-vars are static at Pod creation time; do you experience that same mismatch for a newly created Pod?